# Error: Font \l_tmpa_font has only 8 fontdimen parameters

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math

I get the above error when I try to use my main font for the math letters. If I leave out the `\sqrt[3]{2}` bit, it works but gives a load of complaints about not having the OpenType feature `'Style=MathScriptScript' (+ssty)` available in Calluna. (If you don't have Calluna: TeX Gyre Pagella shows the same  behaviour.) What can I do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calluna}%
\setsansfont{Calluna Sans}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
% If one ore more of the following three lines are included ...
% \setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin}]{Calluna}
% \setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin}]{Calluna-Italic}
% \setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{latin,Latin}]{Calluna-Bold}
\begin{document}\noindent\LARGE 
    % ... this would still work, but fontspec will nag about missing +ssty:
    $a = -\frac{1}{2}$\\
    % ... but this won't work at all:
    $a = -\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried the workaround suggested by Ulrike Fischer in her answer to the linked question, that is adding `\setmathfont[range=\int]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}` after all `\setmathfont` commands. It seems to work. By the way, don't load `xltxtra` unless you specifically need its features (which is unlikely); loading `unicode-math` is sufficient.

Comment: And I had to change the font (as I don't have calluna) and then the document failed completly https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/177.

Comment: @egreg, yes, that works. I haven't got a clue why, but it works. Re xltxtra: in its doc it says that fontspec loads it anyway, so I got rid of that line.

Comment: @Ulrike, that is all way up over my head. But it's good to see people who obviously know what they're talking about working on all this.

Comment: @Blackface It's a weakness of `unicode-math`, that sets up some parameters based on the *last* declared math font. It probably should have separate `\setmainmathfont` and `\setothermathfont`, so it could take the needed parameters from the main font.